# Set a particular propert of all objects in an array in typescript

Tags: typescript

I have the below studentList

```
private studentList:Array<Student>
```

The Student class has a many properties and one of the property is 'status'.
How can i set this 'status' property to a particular value for all the Students in the StudentList array.

I achieved this by doing forEach and setting it .

Is there a better way of doing this? May be avoid the iteration .

Comment: using `.forEach` is probably your best bet. What about the `.forEach` method is unsatisfactory to you? I don't think theres a way to do it without iterating the array in one fashion or another, and `forEach` is likely the most concise way to do so.

Comment: Yup.It works perfectly for me by using forEach. Just trying to see if there are any better ways

Answer (score 1):

> How can i set this 'status' property to a particular value for all the Students in the StudentList array.

Simple [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) would do it.

## Example

```
studentList.forEach(stu => stu.status = 'the value you want');
```

Answer (score 0):

forEach is probably best for a status change. However, if it is an initial value, you are better embedded that as a default inside your Student class.